# Setting Default WebPage in IIS 7.5

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I'd a HD problem in machine where my Intranet IIS server was installed and I've reinstalled all the software. I've restored the site data into new IIS but now, when I type the server address in a browser in a client or even server machine, it doesn't find the page ("Default.aspx"). I can allow "Directory browsing" and click the file but, obviously, I don't want this alternative, neither obligating users to type "Default.aspx" in the end of the URL.

Maybe it's a very simple configuration, but I've cannot found it in IIS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the following in site's or application's web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <add value="~/Default.aspx"/>
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: After you put the above in the appropriate config file, what do you see when you look at the application in the IIS manager? (`IIS Manager -> Sites-> <website in question> -> <IIS Section> Default Document`)?

Comment: I saw "~/Default.aspx" in Entry Type "local". Was not working. Then, I've added just "Default.aspx" entry type "local". Worked fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

When you select your website or application in the left panel, there is an icon named "Default Document" on the middle, under IIS title. That is where that configuration is made from IIS Manager. Current default documents are listed and new ones can be created by clicking Add link on the Actions panel on right.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the answer of same question. But these line helped me to achieve goal.

```
  <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="/Pages/ABC/xyz/" childOnly="true" />
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="~/Default.aspx"/>
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: All pages in `/Pages/ABC/xyz/` redirect to *Default.aspx* ?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem in MVC project where I have put a default.aspx in the root
It was not enough to only set web.config

```
<system.webServer>
<defaultDocument enabled="true">
    <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="Default.aspx" />
    </files>
</defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```

Also had too add
routes.IgnoreRoute(""); in RouteConfig.cs

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("");
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

I followed the guide: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Aug/15/IIS-Default-Documents-vs-ASPNET-MVC-Routes

Comment: Also had too add routes.IgnoreRoute(""); in RouteConfig.cs
This part helped me. on Windows Server 2016